# How to display a lot of non-physical particles using pdb?

Tags: pdb, particle-system

I want to display a lot of particles (~ 20,000) spread over an imaginary cylinder. Certain particles are connected to each other. I wrote a Matlab script for plotting the structure but the computer suffer to handle thousand of particles. So I thought to use an other tool such as Pymol, but I need to create a pdb file.

Does anyone know if it is possible to define non physical particles and which one are connected together?

Thanks =)